# Complex Relationship with Multiple Conditions

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, ssas-tabular

I have two tables `Product` and `Sales`. The `relationship` between two tables all like below ( In Sql)

```
Select *from Product P
Inner Join Sales S
On S.SalesProductID = P.ProductID
and P.TransactionDate Between S.SalesValidFromDate and S.ValidToDate
```

While `Modelling` tables in `Power BI/SSAS` Tabular How do we specify the above relationship between these tables. I Couldn’t find any option to write conditions/expressions in the Relationship options provided. Any suggestions much appreciated. ( I have come across `calculated tables` is that only way to achieve this scenario?)

Comment: Can you post a minimal example what your join would look like with a few variations on your join arguments. I am not sure if Power BI can handle your second join condition. In general you specifiy relationships in Power BI in the `Models` tab on the left pane, per drag and drop.

Comment: i haven't implemented the model yet...got struck in this part. Basically I need to simulate this same sql join condition in power bi

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you will not be able to define that relation in the Power BI model pane. You can create a calculated table like this though:

```
join_table =
FILTER (
    CROSSJOIN ( 'Product'; Sales );
    'Product'[Prod_ID_p] = Sales[Prod_Id] 
        && 'Product'[Trans_Date] >= Sales[Sales_Valid_From]
        && 'Product'[Trans_Date] < Sales[Sales_Valid_To]
)
```

`CROSSJOIN` will complain if there are columns with the same name in both tables, why it's renamed to `Prod_ID_p`.

Comment: Thanks. But instead crossjoin should we need to naturalinnerjoin?

Comment: Nah, those join-operataions require that columns have the same names, which is not your case for the date-part. This is from docs on `NATURALINNERJOIN`: `The tables are joined on common columns (by name) in the two tables. If the two tables have no common column names, an error is returned.`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/naturalinnerjoin-function-dax

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach.

No calculated table is necessary. Create a relationship between Product and Sales using ProductID, and define a measure to aggregate Sales within valid period.

```
Product Sales =
SUMX(
    'Product',
    CALCULATE(
        [Total Sales],
        Sales[SalesValidFromDate] <= 'Product'[TransactionDate]
          && Sales[SalesValidToDate] >= 'Product'[TransactionDate]
    )
)
```

Comment: but , for this measure to work..there should be existing relationship between the tables?

Comment: Relationship 'Product'[ProductID] -> Sales[SalesProductID]  is required.